# How to use String Parameterized in Groovy Script of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have two Jenkins Jobs `JOB A` and `JOB B`. `JOB A` is responsible to trigger `JOB B`.
`JOB A` has a Post-build Action and I am assigning parameter value and that is JSON like below:

[image]

Im `JOB B` I want to use that String parameter and I want to create a JSON file and want to save that im `JOB B`'s workspace.

I used Groovy but am not sure how to access my param `Sample`.

Comment: Is your problem that `JOB B` doesn't get the `Sample` parameter or that you don't know how to access it in Groovy? There's no need for Groovy, however: A simple `echo %Sample% > %WORKSPACE%\Sample.json` in an _Execute Windows batch command_ build step (or a shell-equivalent) in `JOB B` does the trick.

Comment: looks fine you are correct not need of Groovy script , only windows batch do work ..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for Groovy. A simple:

```cmd
echo %Sample% > %WORKSPACE%\Sample.json
```

in an *Execute Windows batch command* build step (or a shell-equivalent) in `JOB B` does the trick, too.

See [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables):

> | Environment Variable | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | WORKSPACE | The absolute path of the workspace. |